# Which services does a Network Device Connection require, on Windows?

Tags: windows, networking

Which services does a Network Device Connection requires on Windows?

I'm only enabling TCP/IP 4 as you can see in the image, and am not using DHCP.

Connection seem fine so far.

Any problems are expected?

[image]

Comment: What you need depends entirely on what your use case is.

Comment: this might be helpful to you: https://www.dummies.com/programming/networking/configuring-network-connections-windows-10/

Answer (score 2):

In the list above:

1. You need Client for Microsoft Networks installed or some connection types may not work. I suggest definitely having this installed and enabled.

> Client for Microsoft Networks is an essential networking software
> component for the Microsoft Windows family of operating systems. A
> Windows computer must run Client for Microsoft Networks to remotely
> access files, printers, and other shared network resources on a
> Windows server.

2. File and Printer sharing installed only for that purpose. Optional, but I often connect to my other computer so I have this enabled.
3. QoS Packet Scheduler:  I keep this enabled. I think it is optional, but I do not disable it.

> Packet scheduling is the means by which data (packet)
> transmission-governing — a key function of quality of service — is
> achieved. The packet scheduler is the traffic control module that
> regulates how much data an application (or flow) is allowed,
> essentially enforcing QOS parameters that are set for a particular
> flow.

4. Microsoft LLPD Protocol Driver:  I keep it enabled but it is optional.

> Microsoft LLDP Protocol Driver: The Link Layer Discovery Protocol
> (LLDP) is a link layer protocol used by network devices for
> advertising their identity, capabilities and neighbors on an IEEE 802
> local area network

If you delete and reinstall your wireless network driver, the ones I listed will be enabled by default. The defaults are good, and there is not any significant performance gain by disabling default settings.

Of my list above, be sure to keep Client for Microsoft Networks enabled.

Comment: “Client for Microsoft Networks” is absolute not required for any browsing. It is only relevant for accessing some types of shared resources (file shares, printers, …) on the local network.

Comment: That may depend upon the connection. I have had this disabled and my connection quit . I had to re-enable it and restart to get connected.  I did change the language to "connection types"